# How can you set the http address in play 2.3.8

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator

I need to run my play application on a specific host name in development mode.

I tried several options e.g.

```
activator -jvm-debug 9999 "run -Dhttp.port=1808 -Dhttp.address=myhost"
```

The port argument gets applied but not the address.
How can I set it?
Help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think the address-part has no DNS, so resolving a hostname into an IP-address does not work.
Maybe it helps if you change the application.baseUrl?

See here for more information:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.x/configuration

Be aware, that the documentation says it's for 1.2.x ... so you'll have to try if it works for 2.3.8

Answer (score 0):

Open the `application.conf` file and add the below line

```
application.baseUrl= "http://hostnameORipaddress:portNumber/"
```

Then run the application with the specified port `run portNumber`